# LNK1104: cannot open file 'lapack.lib' (QT Creator)

Tags: c++, qt, armadillo, lapack

## Goal:

I am trying to use *Armadillo*.

## Problem:

When I build my project I receive the following error:

> Error: "LNK1104: cannot open file 'lapack.lib'"

## Code

*project.pro*:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:\Qt\Armadillo\armadillo\include

LIBS += \
    -LC:\Qt\Armadillo\armadillo\examples\lib_win64 \
    -llapack_win64_MT \
    -lblas_win64_MT
```

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
{
    mat A(2,3);
    A(1,2) = 456.0;
    A.print("A:");

    cout << "Matrix A:" << endl << A << endl;
}
```

## Environment

- I am using QT creator 4.7.0
- Have armadillo-9.100.5
- System is Windows 10

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Try using forward slash instead of backslash in LIBS. Even better is to right click on empty area in pro file and select add library>external library and select your lib file. Qt add all the necessary lines for you.